# MethodError: no method matching my function name in Julia despite the function being exported

Tags: julia

I have a project that defines a few "actions" functions and exports them all. However, when I run my code, it says there is no action that matches the function signature I am looking for. I do `methods(actions)` and I see exactly the function I am looking for there, but at runtime, the action somehow is not visible.

Note that the code calls functions in other packages and the error seems to go away if I prefix the actions method with the name of the package the actions method is being called from: 
`otherPackageWhereTheActionsMethodIsCalled.actions(x, y)`. This works but does not feel like the right thing in this situation. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

(I already verified the function is exported and the code is private so I can't share exactly what is causing this issue.)

The other thing to note is that in the other package, the "closest candidate" is just named "actions" whereas in my package, the actions function is overloading another function `POMDPS.actions(x,y)` which might be part of the issue?

Comment: I guess you should provide an MWE, but could it be that you shadow the function with another local one of the same name?